# PHP - Get key from another key value through a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multidimensional array that is obtained through an API.

```
$exchangeID = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 'vcxz', 
        'currency' => 'GBP',
        ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 'mnbv',
        'currency' => 'EUR',
        ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 'lkjh',
        'currency' => 'USD', 
        ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => 'poiuy',
        'currency' => 'KRN',
        ),
    );
```

I would like to obtain the **id** of USD which is *lkjh*. I know this can be obtained by simply doing $exchangeID[2]['id']. The problem is that the array is dynamic. For example when it is loaded the first subarray may be EUR instead of GBP, and the third subarray may be KRN instead of USD.

Basically, what I have in mind is to look for the subarray where there is the currency first, then accordingly find the corresponding id. E.g. if I want to find EUR. First I find the EUR, then get 'mnbv'.

I tried this `$key = array_search('USD', array_column($exchangeID, 'currency'));` but I got the following error in my error_log `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  array_column()` to get at least the array number e.g. in this case 2.

Comment: It seems that you are using a PHP version lower than 5.5 - In this case you could check this implementation https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php if you want to avoid the PHP fatal error

Comment: does my answer work? if so let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply filter your array, like this:

```
$usd_exchanges = array_filter($exchangeID, function($row) {
  return $row['currency'] == "USD";
}));
var_dump($usd_exchanges[0]);
```

You can also return the first element of the filter, using the `current` method:

```
$usd_exchange = current(array_filter($exchangeID, function($row) {
  return $row['currency'] == "USD";
})));
var_dump($usd_exchange);
```

Comment: Plus for `array_filter` + `current`. Might want to add obtaining the id only (not the entire data-set).

Comment: this will work, but might waste time after the key has been found - this will check every record in the array, and continue after the key has been found :o until the list is exhausted

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($exchangeID as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($exchangeID[$key]['currency']=='USD'){
            $usdId=$exchangeID[$key]['id'];
      break;
        }
    }
//echo $usdId; 
//Result:ikjh
```

Comment: Minus for using echo.

Comment: adding a break; will make it faster - the current code keeps looking until the list is exhausted, while it _should_ stop asap when the key has been found

Comment: Removed echo, added break.happy? Hehe :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($exchangeID as $key => $arr)
  if($arr['currency'] == 'USD')
    echo $key;
```

It is possible to use following custom function to get the key:

```
echo getKeyRecursive('USD', $exchangeID);
function getKeyRecursive($needle, $haystack, $strict = false)
{
  foreach ($haystack as $key => $item){
     if(($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && getKeyRecursive($needle, $item, $strict))) return $key;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$exchangeID = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 'vcxz', 
        'currency' => 'GBP',
        ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 'mnbv',
        'currency' => 'EUR',
        ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 'lkjh',
        'currency' => 'USD', 
        ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => 'poiuy',
        'currency' => 'KRN',
        ),
    );
$db=new PDO('sqlite::memory:','','',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$db->query('CREATE TABLE `troll` (`dbid` TEXT, `dbcurrency` TEXT);');
$stm=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `troll` (`dbid`,`dbcurrency`) VALUES(:id,:currency);");
array_walk($exchangeID,function($arr)use($stm){$stm->execute($arr);});
$res=$db->query("SELECT `dbid` AS `id` FROM `troll` WHERE `dbcurrency` = ".$db->quote('USD').' LIMIT 1');

$id=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id=$id['id'];
var_dump($id);
```

see working example here http://codepad.viper-7.com/1lg2Gj

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this works:

```
  foreach($exchangeID as $key => $val)
  {
      if(array_key_exists('currency', $val))
        if($val['currency'] == 'USD'){
          echo $val['id'];
          echo $val['currency'];
        elseif($val['currency'] == 'GBP'){a1
           echo $val['id'];
          echo $val['currency']);
       elseif($val['currency'] == 'EUR'){
          echo $val['id'];
         echo $val['currency'];
         }else{
          echo $val['id'];
         echo $val['currency'];
       }
    }
  }
```